# Error passing closure to function in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have written a closure within a Groovy script to copy files, and then I pass that closure to eachFileMatch(regex, closure) to copy all files that match the given regex. When I prototyped it in the Groovy Console everything worked just fine but now when I run it in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.eachFileMatch() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.regex.Pattern, file_copy$_run_closure3)
```

Here is the closure and the call to eachFileMatch()

```
def fileCopyClosure = {

if(it.canRead()){
    def destFolder = new File("${outputDirectory}")
    if(!destFolder.exists()){
        println "Creating directory"
        destFolder.mkdir()
    }


    def desti = new File("${outputDirectory}\\${it.name}")
    output = desti.newOutputStream()
    it.eachByte(1024, write)
    output.close()

}
}
sourceDir.eachFileMatch(regex, fileCopyClosure)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `new File(sourceDir).eachFileMatch(regex, fileCopyClosure)`

Comment: As soon as you point it out, it seems so obvious. Thanks for the second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

from the exception, `sourceDir` is a String, not a `File` that you need for `eachFileRecurse`